# ICMP in Windows 10 Universal Apps

Tags: sockets, windows-10, win-universal-app, icmp

I would like to be able to do some ICMP network diagnostics from a windows 10 universal app, including ping, traceroute, etc.

However it would appear that the `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` class isn't available to store apps and when creating a new `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` the ProtocolType.Icmp is not available when I try.

All the information I can find on the Internet about this topic all relates to windows 8.1 apps and I want to know if anything new has been added to the API in Windows 10 that would allow me to produce ICMP ping, etc.

I've seen suggestions that you could use raw sockets but it appears that these are no longer allowed on client versions of Windows.

My preferred language is C# but I'm OK with using C++ if this gives me an advantage.

Note: checking the network status is not sufficient. I'm actually wanting to test the connection to specific machines on the network, I really do want a proper ICMP ping.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping dot net class is a wrapper for the Win32 IP Helper Functions.

UWP Apps run in a protected environment, and as a result, many Win32, COM, and CRT API calls that might compromise the security of the platform are not allowed.

Windows Runtime apps and Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps can use a subset of the Win32 and COM APIs which you can call in a native app.

Unfortunately, the Win32 IP Helper Functions are not supported in UWP yet.