# C# ping not working

Tags: c#

I have this ping line

```
new Ping().Send("8.8.8.8").RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms";
```

but it throws an error stating :

> Type or namespace 'Ping' could not be found

I've already tried to import `System.Net` with `using System.Net;` but with no luck.

I am building a `Universal Windows Application` (will ran using the `Windows 10 IoT`)

it might be basic stuff, but I'm new to C#.

Comment: The Ping class isn't in System.Net, so that's why it can't find it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I added `using System.Net.NetworkInformation;` but still no luck

Comment: Unfortunatly it looks like Ping isn't supported on some of the platforms UWAs support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040753/icmp-in-windows-10-universal-apps so it's not available.

Comment: I see... well then, guess I'll have to figure out another method. do you by accident know a way to do this?

Comment: are you referencing `System.dll` ? It contains the Ping class

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs One (not very good) solution is running a server somewhere that you use to do the ping. So you call the server using http, the server makes the ping, the server replies with the ping results over http.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, unfortunately, I only have the raspberry pi to do it all.

Answer (score 2):

import System.Net.NetworkInformation.

A good trick is to use the Object Browser in Visual Studio to find your missing class. You can search for Ping and the Object Browser will show you what namespace you need.

Comment: yes. when I say 'no luck' it basically means nothing good has happened

Answer (score 2):

System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping is currently not available in Universal Windows Applications. The Windows API call it uses isn't present on all platforms.

[ICMP in Windows 10 Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040753/icmp-in-windows-10-universal-apps)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Directive

If the Type cannot be found, ensure that you've added the correct **using
directive**.

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

When hoovering over the `Ping`-Type keyword it then must show you `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` otherwise the assembly is not found.

#### Reference

Looking up the Ping-Class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) informs about in which dll the class is located. In this Case it is the `System.dll`. Make sure to add it in your **Project References**

#### Else

If this doesn't work too, I suppose that you somehow declared a custom namespace which hides the namespace of the Ping class.

So if you write your code **inside** a `System.Net.NetworkInformation`-Namespace as follows (or even `System.Net`):

```
namespace System.Net.NetworkInformation 
{
    class MyClass 
    {

    }   
}
```

this would hide the requested namespace. I suggest using another namespace in this case.

#### Note

For sure I didn't catch all possibilities in the else part. So please add completion in comments and I will add them.

Comment: Thanks for your nice and detailed response, but unfortunately, I learned that `Universal Windows Application` do not support the ping command :\

Comment: your welcome. According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/256bda77-6004-4399-b8d2-890dc24d9725/sending-ping-using-sockets?forum=winappswithcsharp) you are right.. allthough I dont understand why this doesnt exist.

Comment: yea, I don't understand it either... I heard some people say it was due to `security reasons` but I don't know how a ping command would be a big security issue... since you can always just SSH into the machine and run a ping command trough the shell.... (unfortunately, the C# library for powershell commands is removed too)

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs somehow they don't want us to be networking with those apps.

Comment: well... you can start a webcontrolled script thingy on the IoT... but not ping a computer? :p legit

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs & LuckyLikey:  Frameworks that target multiple platforms can only include features that work on all platforms. In this case the Ping class doesn't perform the ping itself, it calls a Windows API to do it. That API doesn't exist on all the platforms, that means that feature isn't available in the framework. Now it would be possible to create an implementation that work work everywhere, but that can be a lot of effort and often comes later. This is why (imo) cross-platform targeting sucks. You're choosing to restrict what you can do, to increase your targets.

Comment: @andyj seems legit to me. Another concept would be to provide platform independent feautures withe the possibility for soecial changes to each platdorm and version. If you are familiar with the ionic framework, you might know this concept. - sorry for misstypings, using handyapp